# How to use environment variable with IIS user

Tags: web-services, wcf, ant, cmd, windows-server-2012

I have a WCF service that runs a `.bat` file. It works on my local system, but I have a problem with running it on the server (Windows server 2012 r2).

I've defined the `ANT_HOME` variable to server's environment variables and I've added `%ANT_HOME%\bin` to `Path` variable.

When I write "`ant`" to CMD on the server it works! But when I call the `wcf` service from somewhere, it doesn't work.

I found the following error in the log files:

```
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

According to this log, I understand that IIS user cannot use the `ANT_HOME` variable which is already defined.

What I have tried so far:

- identity impersonate
- giving full permission to IIS user

Comment: Did you edit the PATH user environment variable of the PATH system environment variable? Did you restart Windows so it picks up the modified PATH?

Answer (score 0):

What version of IIS are you running? If you are running a version where you can create a separate [Application Pool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731784(v=ws.10).aspx) for your service then do so and give this Application Pool an identity that has the right PATH or defines ANT_HOME for that user. I always like adding a Ping type method to all my services so I can ask the service who it is running as and where it is running. It is great for troubleshooting and testing WCF services.