# Add environment variable to an IIS User account

Tags: asp.net, iis, cmd, environment-variables

I want to add a system variable in Windows specific to an IIS user account. Is this possible? I do not want to install anything to/modify my IIS installation.

I have tried searching for this over the internet but couldn't find a solution. Also, what I understood from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378507/how-to-use-environment-variable-with-iis-user) post is, that I would need to change the user under which the application pool runs. I do not want to do that either.

Comment: How about setting it by code on Application_Start by using SetEnvironmentVarialbe. Check the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That depends on if the environment variable set in `Application_Start` is going to be available to the subsequent processes that are started from the code. I believe not.